# Is there a sotfware to create, manager and CAML query SharePoint Lists without having SharePoint installed on a computer?

Tags: list, caml, query, database, offline

I'm working on a SharePoint site at work, however due to PCI compliance I am not able to access SharePoint at my house, I was trying to find a software on which I can be able to create lists and use CAML queries on them wihtout having Sharepoint, I have found some applications but they need me to connect to SharePoint, is there any way I can do this offline for practice and planning?

I am targeting for some sort of DBMS like software that can manage SP Lists.

Answer (score 0):

There is no offline mode to edit or manage SharePoint site. But there is you can thing about more advanced alternatives by using [PnP](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP), like:

1. Register to [Office 365 developer program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev-program)  and create developer Office 365 tenant, where you could have your own SharePoint environment for development purposes.
2. Use this SharePoint environment for list, field and content type management.
3. When you are done you can export your site to PnP provisioning templates. It can be done using [PnP Powershell](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell). Command [Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps) template allows you to specify witch artifacts to export. You will get XML file with all your customization.
4. Later at your work you can use this exported XML template and import your customization to you production environment by using [Apply-PnPProvisiongTemplate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/apply-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps).

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own virtual machines with SharePoint installed. You would then have the same version as your on-prem SharePoint. If you don't have a PC at home suitable for VMs this large, consider building them in Azure VMs. There are even preinstalled SharePoint 2013, 2016 and 2019 VMs available in Azure, all you need to add is an Azure SQL Server or an Azure VM with SQL installed to get it running. As long as you shut the VMs down when not in use, your only ongoing costs are the VM disk image storage costs.